# How to run unit test for angular httpbasedservice?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have forked a service from this very good site http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html. I was playing around with the httpBasedservice:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('httpBasedService', function($http) {
  return {
    sendMessage: function(msg) {    
      return $http.get('somthing.json?msg=' + msg)
        .success(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        })
        .error(function(){
          //
        })
    }
  };
});
```

How can I make the test for the httpBasedservice pass?
plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/9yNZUpLpoTk9awNwGGEM?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assert against the `response.data` property rather than the whole response object.

```
returnedPromise.then(function(response) {
    result = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your test case since you are making a async call and expecting this to the result data ..

**this is what you are expecting ..**

```
expect(result).toEqual(returnData);
```

but since it is a async call you will not get result instantly so your test case fails.

**so you need to do something like this.**

```
 var result;
    returnedPromise.then(function(response) {
      result = response;
      expect(result.data).toEqual(returnData);
    });
```

[Here is the working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqdAZLyMnLW61ts7ol3Y?p=preview)